# How to prevent page skipping before sections?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, page

I'm fairly new to latex and I'm not the sharpest around programming, and I'm using overleaf. In the report class the page is skipped before chapter titles and that's fine but how do I redefine sections (and subs) so it does not happen there?
Basically I'd want the chapters to be on a new page and all lower hierarchies to continue on the same page

Comment: By default that doesn't happen,  so show a small but complete example that can be used to test your issue.

Comment: I wrote as follows:

`\begin{document}

\include{capitoli/Introduction.tex}
\include{capitoli/Mycobacterium_abscessus.tex}

\end{document}`

Where the introduction chapter is currently blank and only has its own title. The rendered pages are [these](https://imgur.com/a/fb1eF3H).
Everything else about the formatting is as it should be.

Comment: don't use `\include`, it forces a new page, use `\input`.